progress bar using ProgressBarLogger via websocket
I want to upload a file to a fastapi endpoint,inside this endpoint i have a function that use moviepy to subclip and extract the audio,then write that audio to a file using audio_clip.write_audiofile(audio_name,logger=log).
This logger is very important it is the  responsible for showing the progress,it is an instance of ProgressBarLogger,in each time the progress value changes a callback function inside the logger object calls,therefore we can use it to send the current progress to the front-end,i am trying to do that using websockets, so i did the following:
@app.websocket("/proces")
async def process_file(websocket:WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    data=await websocket.receive_text()
    data=json.loads(data)
    print(data)
    await websocket.send_text(f"recieved{data}")
    logger=MyBarLogger(websocket)
    audio=media_clip_audio(f"uploaded_files/{data['file_name']}",data["start_time"],data["end_time"],logger)

her is MyBarLogger class:
 
class MyBarLogger(ProgressBarLogger):

    def __init__(self,websocket:WebSocket):
        super().__init__()
        self.wbs=websocket
    async def sc(self,p):
       print("trying to send a message")
       await (self.wbs).send_text({"data":p})
    def bars_callback(self, bar, attr, value,old_value=None):
        # Every time the logger progress is updated, this function is called            
        self.percentage = (value / self.bars[bar]['total']) * 100
        global progress
        progress=self.percentage
        asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(self.sc(self.percentage))
        print("prg",progress)


and the used part in media_clip_audio function is that:



def media_clip_audio(media_path, start_time, end_time,log):

        clip =VideoFileClip(media_path)

        cut_clip = clip.subclip(start_time, end_time)
   
        audio_clip = cut_clip.audio

        audio_name = "tsstss.wav"
        audio_clip.write_audiofile(audio_name,logger=log)

here is the code from the client :
function process(){

            var info={
        "start_time":startTime,
        "end_time":endTime,
        "file_name":uploadedFilename};
        let infostring=JSON.stringify(info);
        console.log("serial",infostring);           
        
        const ws= new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8000/proces');


      
        ws.addEventListener('open',(event)=>{

        console.log("connected");
        console.log("info",info);
        ws.send(infostring);
        });
        ws.onmessage= function(event){

        console.log(event.data);

        };

however i see that problem:  File "/home/my_mcap_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/starlette/_exception_handler.py", line 50, in sender
await send(message)
File "/home/my_mcap_env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/protocols/websockets/websockets_impl.py", line 359, in asgi_send
raise RuntimeError(msg % message_type)
RuntimeError: Unexpected ASGI message 'websocket.send', after sending 'websocket.close' or response already completed
why that problem happened and how to solve it?
